Vumanchu - MFRSI Calculation
For one of my tradingbots I want to use Vumanchu Cipher B indicator of which the source code is public and can be found here.
I want to convert the code to python, everything seems to be working in line when I check it against the actual indicator and correct broker on Tradingview, except for the MRFRSI calculation.
Pine function MFRSI:
// RSI+MFI
f_rsimfi(_period, _multiplier, _tf) => security(syminfo.tickerid, _tf, sma(((close - open) / (high - low)) * _multiplier, _period) - rsiMFIPosY)

My python code for the Vumanchi Cipher B indicator in Python is as follows:
import pandas_ta as ta

def vumanchu_indicator():
# variables basis cipher B settings
    n1 = 9  # channel length
    n2 = 12  # average length

    df['ap'] = (df.high + df.low + df.close) / 3  # WT ma source
    df['esa'] = ta.ema(df.ap, n1)  # EMA of the ma source by the channel length
    df['d'] = ta.ema(abs(df.ap - df.esa), n1)
    df['ci'] = (df.ap - df.esa) / (0.015 * df.d)
    df['wt1'] = ta.ema(df.ci, n2)
    df['wt2'] = ta.sma(df.wt1, 3)
    df["volume"] = df["tick_volume"]

    # MF RSI
    # variables
    period = 60
    multi = 150
    posy = 2.5

    df['mfrsi'] = ta.ema(((df.close - df.open) / (df.high - df.low)) * multi, period) - posy

    # moving averages
    df['ma50'] = ta.ema(df.close, 50)
    df['ma200'] = ta.ema(df.close, 200)

    # Calculate crossing points
    df["green_wt"] = (df['wt1'] > df['wt2']) & (df['wt1'].shift(1) <= df['wt2'].shift(1))
    df["red_wt"] = (df['wt1'] < df['wt2']) & (df['wt1'].shift(1) >= df['wt2'].shift(1))
    
    return


Values differ significantly from what I see on Tradingview in the indicator, where the MFRSI is way thicker on the cart and in number than in the calculations I get out of it.
Am I overlooking something?
In the source code of Vumanchu they mention for _tf that also Heikin Ashi candles are used, tried to use that as input as well but still get wrong output.
